# How to train p(category|title) model with word2vec

Tags: word2vec

Using word2vec, the goal is to maximize the corpus probability p(word|context), and context comes in the form of words.

Suppose given a corpus Titles and their category(such as sport, food...), how to use word2vec to train a model to predict p(category|title).

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do your own naive compositionality by adding the words in the title together to get a vector that "describes" the whole sentence. Once you have that vector, you can train any classifier on it (SVM, logistic regression, k-nearest neighbors, etc).

This method may be simple enough to work, depending on how long these titles are. word2vec embeddings have been shown to exhibit some compositionality under simple vector addition for short phrases (in the word2vec paper, Mikolov et al show vec("Germany") + vec("capital") gets pretty close to vec("Berlin"). So maybe that'll be good enough for you.

Alternatively, if the titles are more like sentence, you could consider using the sentence-level extension of word2vec from Quoc Le & Tomas Mikolov's paper. Gensim has a pretty straightforward-to-use implementation of it called doc2vec.

http://rare-technologies.com/doc2vec-tutorial/

Just like the simpler vector addition idea, doc2vec will produce a fixed-length representation of your title, which you can then feed into standard ML libraries for classification.